# Create element based on UserInput

Tags: reactjs

**[FIXED]**

I'm new to reactjs. Trying to create an element based on user input, which it generates below the input box side by side, but it does not seem to generate it. Not getting any errors either.

I think the error could be on *line 6* where I'm adding the *' else if'* statement but not sure what's going wrong there.
Thanks

ISSUE FIXED - I got the barebones working, with some help here's the blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-evgduq

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  function getData(val) {
    setData(val.target.value);
    console.log(data);

    if (data < 2) {
      //genarate div based on value (data)
      return <BigElement />;
    } else if (data > 2) {
      return <SmallElement />;
    } else {
      console.log('error');
    }
  }
 //declaring small and big elements here
function BigElement(val) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    console.log('add');
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.classList.add('div-style');
  }

  function SmallElement(val) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div2');
    console.log('add2');
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.classList.add('div-style2');
  }
//InputBox
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="maintext">Enter Tasks</h1>
      <input type="text" className="input1" id="inp1" onChange={getData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

StackBltiz Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7ytjik?file=src/App.js
[image: What I Want]

Comment: To be honest, there's ***a lot*** wrong here.  Directly manipulating the DOM in React, trying to return a component from an event handler, trying to access state before it's been updated, etc.  Now is a good time to take several steps back and start with some introductory React tutorials.  Specifically focus on how to use a state value to dynamically render components in the JSX result. At *no* point should you be using things like `createElement` or `appendChild` in React. Instead, all of the markup you want to use should be in the JSX already and is conditionally shown/hidden based on state.

Comment: I was following the official react js website and a few tuts online. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

dont update state directly as rendering is disabled and react dont understand if you updated your state and always controll your input by yourself

```
[state , setState] = useState('')

<input value={state} onChange ={(e) => setState(e.target.value)} />
```